# Unable to install Scipy using pip install command

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pip

I am having this

```
Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

configuration and installing scipy on Python but I get this error and fail to understand the issue. Please remain on Python and not Anaconda and others.

```
(pip3py3) C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\a>pip install scipy-0.19.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\x\pycharmprojects\a\scipy-0.19.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\pip3py3\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\x\pip3py3\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\x\pip3py3\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\x\pip3py3\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\x\pip3py3\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Users\x\pip3py3\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg\pip\download.py", line 809, in unpack_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Users\x\pip3py3\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg\pip\download.py", line 715, in unpack_file_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "C:\Users\x\pip3py3\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "C:\Users\x\pip3py3\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 484, in unzip_file
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\zipfile.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\zipfile.py", line 1113, in _RealGetContents
    fp.seek(self.start_dir, 0)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the WHL file from [Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) with `pip install <filename>.whl`? This is often a nice workaround when the package from PyPI won't install.

Comment: I m installing from here only

Comment: Oops, sorry. Didn't see that...

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was somewhat strange. I solved it by installing numpy+mkl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and then scipy installation worked for me.

Comment: @shrutiiyyer Yes I did pip install only